# Powershell Where-Object Match

Tags: powershell

I want to use the `Where-Object` to limit the Output of `Get-PSDrive` to only network shares.

`Get-PSDrive` shows me the following:

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                       CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                       ---------------
A                                      FileSystem    A:\                                                       
Alias                                  Alias                                                                   
C                  16.19         43.47 FileSystem    C:\                                  Users\HansB\Documents
Cert                                   Certificate   \                                                         
D                                      FileSystem    D:\                                                       
Env                                    Environment                                                             
Function                               Function                                                                                                 
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER                                         
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE                                        
V                 451.39        159.76 FileSystem    \\192.168.71.31\fs_log_target                             
Variable                               Variable                                                                
W                 197.72               FileSystem    \\192.168.71.32\perf200                                   
WSMan                                  WSMan                                                                   
X                 197.72               FileSystem    \\192.168.71.32\perf100                                   
Y                 271.52         34.33 FileSystem    \\192.168.71.30\group200                                  
Z                 271.52         34.33 FileSystem    \\192.168.71.30\group100
```

Then I want to get the `\\192.168.71.30\group100` Network Share:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object  { $_.Root -match "\\\\192.168.71.30\\group100" }
```

But I get nothing, why does -match not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use DisplayRoot instead of Root property

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object  { $_.DisplayRoot -match "\\\\192.168.71.30\\group100" }
```

try to run

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object  { $_.DisplayRoot -match "\\\\192.168.71.30\\group100" } | select *
```

Root will be your mapped drive letter, and DisplayRoot your UNC Path

EDIT: as a side note. For escaping regex use [regex]::Escape() method.

```
PS > [regex]::Escape("\\192.168.71.30\group100")
\\\\192\.168\.71\.30\\group100
```

Comment: Best answer - Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-eq` instead:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Root -eq "\\192.168.71.30\group100"}
```

Comment: TESTED: -eq does also result nothing

Answer (score 0):

If yoy type `Get-PSDrive | select root` you will notice that for network drives it will print nothing. So there is something strange with network share roots.

`Get-PSDrive | select root | %{write-host $_.Root.GetType()}` will show that it's a system string, so not quite sure why it seems to be empty for network drives.

Comment: Or look at Adam Mnich answer instead :) ....

Get-PSDrive | select Displayroot does indeed show the wanted string